# vuejs2 reusable code in N tabs

Tags: duplicates, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have 5 tabs with the same user's data. Each tab has an input to search by term. How can  reuse code for fetching users and searching them in opened tab. Code is in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/3/):

```
var listing = Vue.extend({
    data: function () {
        return {
            query: '',
            list: [],
            user: '',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedList: function () {
            var vm = this;
            return this.list.filter(function (item) {
                return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            })
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.loadItems();
    },
    methods: {
        loadItems: function () {
            this.list = ['mike','bill','tony'],
        },
    }
});
var list1 = new listing({
    template: '#users-template'
});

var list2 = new listing({
    template: '#users-template2'
});

Vue.component('list1', list1);
Vue.component('list2', list2)

var app = new Vue({
   el: ".lists-wrappers",
});
```

query - string of term to search

ComputedList - array of filtered data by search term.

But getting error  for "query" and "ComputedList".

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "query" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close with what you had. The reason for the `query` error is you were using `query` in what looked like, to Vue, the root instances scope. You shouldn't put templates *inside* of other templates. Always have them outside of it (preferably as a string in your component definition).

You can read about that a bit here: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Here's how I'd approach your situation: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/apokjqxx/6/

Comment: Thanks! That is what I need.